How to remove maven dependencies downloaded by a particular build?
Like, I have some deps in local repo, then create (clone) a new project, build it (id downloads plethora of deps), then I want to remove the project I've cloned and also remove downloaded maven deps from local repo - those downloaded by that build.
I know some of those could be used by oter local projects, but is there a way to manage it? Maybe storing those deps in project dir only like with NPM projects?

What is the reason you want this? If you store dependencies by project, you will likely have a lot of dependencies multiple times, redownloading takes time and you waste disk space.

Thanks - valid point - in my case , wanted to clean up after done with a project.

To save disk space?

If I remember correctly, you can set per-project cache directory with the maven.repo.local flag:
$ mvn -Dmaven.repo.local={project-dir}/dependencies clean install

This way, when you delete your project, the downloaded deps will be deleted with it.
